Xamarin Forms with RestSharp Authorization Bearer
[The problem]:
The request works in Postman, however the server responded “Unauthorized” from mobile app request.
[The code]:
var options = new RestClientOptions(MyBaseEndpoint)
{
  MaxTimeout = -1,
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
var request = new RestRequest(MyEndpoint, Method.Get);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer MyToken");
var body = MyJson;
request.AddStringBody(body, DataFormat.Json);
RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);


“Does not work” is not a helpful description of the problem

“Unauthorized” is the correct word, @Jason
